# One simple Rebus, I think

Tags: wordplay, visual, rebus

The answer to the Rebus is: Two connected phrases made of 4 words.

Which of the 3 versions below correctly paraphrases the answer?

1. Won by a whole lot of points
2. A whole number for you to see through
3. Nothing escapes this sports achievement

One version correctly paraphrases the answer. Which one is it? Why? What is the 4 word answer?

[image: a three dimensional number one with an opening that you can see through. Relevant text duplicated above.]

Comment: Would it be possible to pare the picture down to just the 1 with a hole in it, add an appropriate image description, and transcribe the text? (If you don't want to do this I can - I'm just checking if it would be acceptable to you). And while I'm at it, is the extraneous space before the comma in the title intended?

Comment: Go ahead @bobble

Comment: @DrD it would be better for the original poster to do so, but I can instead if you're not able to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the answer may be

> Black Hole In One

And so the relevant version which paraphrases the answer is

> 3

My reasoning

> The "hole in one" part is something that is immediate for this rebus (for me, at least) hence the relevant version must be the "sporting achievement". This leaves one linking phrase to obtain to make the entire answer four words in length. The "nothing escapes" part of the version 3 paraphrasing leads me to believe that "black hole" is involved as nothing escapes from behind its event horizon thus leading to the answer-smashed phrase "Black Hole In One".